# It would be great to see your progress towards badges...similar to how progress for privileges are handled

Tags: feature-request, badges

Does anyone else think that it would be great for users to see progress towards certain badges...similar to how users can see their progress towards privileges.

For privileges, you see a % complete towards that privilege. I know that this info is tracked so I think it would be great so that it is revealed or visualized in some way.

Comment: Can you specify which badges you had in mind? Thinking of, for example, the nice/good/great question/answer badges, this wouldn't scale too well for people with dozens or hundreds of questions/answers.

Comment: I think that potentially for ones that can recur, you don't keep track of it after they've earned it once. I think a progress gauge would help lots for the hard to achieve badges.

Answer (score 2):

Separately from my comment: This probably won't happen. If you refer to the corresponding [Meta Stack Overflow request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3230/141911), it references an even earlier request that was declined.

It's a popular request, for sure, but the owners/developers are actively against it.

There is *one* exception: Your progress toward the [Copy Editor](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor) badge (and possibly also [Strunk & White](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) - I can't tell because I already have it) is shown on the [/review page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/review/). That seems to be about as far as they're willing to go.

Comment: I can confirm: The progress toward the "Strunk & White" badge is shown in the "review" page. I know it because it is show in a site where I don't have that badge.